# Android Turnbased multiplayer detected incorrect implementation Google Play Game Services alert

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have published an Android app using the Google Play Game service and have been informed of an alert that says it has "Detected incorrect implementation". Investigating what this means I found that...

This game has implemented invitations but doesn't allow users to join a match from an invitation. This approach is discouraged because it could result in a poor user experience.

Since I based this game on the sample project (TypeANumber) I am unsure what I need to do to comply with this alert. What should I be looking for in the code that would cause this alert, since I have invited and played against my friends quite happily and not experienced such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered (and now cleared) this alert. I suggest the following:

If you have implemented the OnInvitationReceivedListener  i.e.

```
class myClass extends Fragment implements OnInvitationReceivedListener, ...
```

and do not want to handle this yourself, then simply remove OnInvitationReceivedListener from your
implements clause. This is what I did, and it cleared the alert.

Alternatively, if you do want to handle the invitation, then as well as having the OnInvitationReceivedListener in the implements clause you also need to register the invitation listener at run time i.e.

```
Games.Invitations.registerInvitationListener(getApiClient(), this)
```

and provide the listener code i.e.

```
public void onInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation) {
      ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @IanB, but I have the listener code there already, as in the tbmpSkeleton sample

Comment: // Handle notification events.
    @Override
    public void onInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation) {
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "An invitation has arrived from "
                        + invitation.getInviter().getDisplayName(), TOAST_DELAY)
                .show();
    }

Comment: Have you registered the listener, because I think that was missing from the sample ?

Comment: Yes. This line of code is in the function OnSignInSucceeded()

Comment: Games.Invitations.registerInvitationListener(getApiClient(), this);

Comment: Perhaps the Alert is telling me that the Standard behaviour, using notifications, is what is required?

Comment: Tony, is the listener registered on the MainActivity ?

Comment: The listener is registered in OnSignInSucceeded, which is a function of the main activity, yes.